# How to use select on azure search suggesters

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure search on my project, and I want to do an autocomplete text field, it works as expected. here's the code :

```
const suggestItems = async (req, res) => {

try {

    // Reading inputs from HTTP Request

    const q = (req.query.q || (req.body && req.body.q));

    const top = (req.query.top || (req.body && req.body.top));

    const suggester = (req.query.suggester || (req.body && req.body.suggester));

    // Let's get the top 5 suggestions for that search term

    const suggestions = await client.suggest(q, suggester, {  top: parseInt(top) });

    //const suggestions = await client.autocomplete(q, suggester, {top: parseInt(top)});

    console.log(suggestions.results)

    return res.status(status.OK)

    .json({ suggestions: suggestions.results})

   

} catch (error) {

    handleError(res, error)

}

 }
```

her's the result :

```
[

{ text: 'Alpha Aromatics (MA)', document: { id: '4' } },

{ text: 'Alpha Aromatics (USA)', document: { id: '5' } },

{ text: 'Art Land - Winter Palace', document: { id: '6' } },

 { text: 'Alpha Aromatics (USA)', document: { id: '3' } }

]
```

here's the quesry passed by postman :

```
{

"q":"ar","top":5,"suggester":"sg"

 }
```

but the problem is , on the result I have just the text and the id of the document , I'm looking for other fields like status for example, how can get that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing "Status" is one of your index fields, from the question. You need to make sure you mark the fields you need to be returned in the results as `retrievable` in your index definition. It looks you only have text and id fields as `retrievable`. For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index.

Example:

[image]

Comment: thanks for you answer, but all the fields are retrievable, should I use the select key on code ?

Comment: You'r welcome. Yes, you should use select for each field. For more details of how to use it or any other options to manipulate the results, you can see the sample code here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-java#3---search-an-index